# Rules for pronuciation

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology, inflectional-morphology

What are the pronunciation rules for words ending with the 's" sound ? I simply can not remember these rules and can not seem to find the answer in any of my text books. Can anyone by chance help or guide me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Words that end in the /s/ sound always end in the /s/ sound.

Comment: Well that is exactly how the question is asked in the question paper I have for an assignment !?

Comment: [The connection between English spelling and pronunciation is one of the most complex mappings between written letters and spoken pronunciation of any language.](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/pronunciation-vs-spelling/info) English enjoys a many-to-many mapping between spellings and pronunciations insofar as any one spelling can have many pronunciations and any one pronunciation can have many spellings; furthermore, these sets can overlap in highly non-obvious ways. **Are you  asking for “rules” mapping the ‹s› spelling to pronunciations, the /s/ pronunciation to spellings, or both?**